# Only TLS connection shutdown

Tags: ssl, boost, tcp, boost-asio

LDAPServer and LDAPClient, client and server are connecting to each other using TLS and working fine, but i have some usecase to stop only TLS connection and used same TCP connection to communicate to LDAPserver

Below in my ldapperl client code to stop only TLS Connection,

```
my $socket = $ldapSrvr->socket();
print $socket;
print "\n";
my $host  = $ldapSrvr->host();
print $host;
print "\n";
my $ssl = ${*$socket}{'_SSL_object'};
print $ssl;
print "\n";
my $s1 = Net::SSLeay::shutdown($ssl);
print "s1 : $s1";
print "\n";
my $s2 = Net::SSLeay::shutdown($ssl);
print "SSL socket is shutdown : $s2";
print "\n";
${*$socket}{'_SSL_opened'} = 0;
my $t = &Net::SSLeay::clear(${*$socket}{'_SSL_object'});
&Net::SSLeay::print_errs();
untie(*$socket);
```

and server side to stop the only tls connection.

```
  LOG("SSLConnection::disconnect");
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  m_sslSocket.shutdown(ec);

  LOG("[Comms] errorcode while SSLshutdown : ",ec);

  LOG("[Comms] SSL socket is closed");
```

But it is closing the TCP connection also.
when client send sslconnection close request to server, then server is sending FIN ACK to client and TCP connection is getting closed.
Can some tell me why this is happening

http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/Castor/html/classasio_1_1ssl_1_1stream.html#ac70bbb97fe4bc58aa23481cd98c91297

Comment: 'Some use-case' such as what? Why on earth having established a secure connection would you then want to lose that security?

Answer (score 0):

You don't...

Shutdown the ssl socket when you need to close the socket only.

If you wish to communicate directly to the tcp socket then all you need to do with use the "[next_layer()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/next_layer.html)" member to get at the underlying socket class and send it that way.

e.g.

```
m_sslSocket.next_layer().async_send(...);
```

So from your downgraded point onwards you have to remember to do all your socket access through the next_layer() method.

Just remember this will only work if the server you have connected to knows that you have dropped back to using the stream as a non-ssl stream (I assume through some sort of protocol support).  I have never seen this in action, I have seen the opposite with the STMP protocol connected as non-secure and then converting it to a secure connection with [STARTTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207) command.  This is not recommended as it allows for man in the middle attacks to stop the conversation to secure communications.  I would think the same would apply to downgrading a connection as well.